# What is the total internal energy of a liter of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, estimation

How does one calculate the total internal energy of a liter of water? For an ideal gas, the case is simple. $E = c*n*T$, where c is the molar heat capacity, $n$ number of moles, and $T$ the temperature, and because it is an ideal gas, $c$ is only dependent on whether the gas is monatomic, diatomic, etc.

However for a liter of water, $c$ is a function of temperature, and not to mention there is a phase change to ice, so simply integrating over $c$ is also an issue.

How then would I calculate the total internal energy of a liter of water given its temperature? Is there some constant I can multiply by temperature and moles that already has the above effects baked in?

Comment: *How does one calculate the total internal energy of a liter of water?* We don't. We're only interested in **changes** of internal energy. Hint: would you include in an internal energy calc. also the *nuclear energy* of 1L of water?

Comment: @sammygerbil using the value of c for the current temperature of the water is only accurate for *changes* in the internal energy *around that temperature*. I need the total internal energy for which using the heat capacity at only one temperature would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a constant factor as you ask for - applying at all temperatures - could not exist, because specific heat capacity varies with temperature (as you have said), and there are discontinuities at phase transitions.

Nevertheless you could still make a calculation quite easily, integrating numerically over values of SHC for ice then water from $1K$ up to your target temperature, adding the latent heat of vaporisation if appropriate.

Tables of specific heat capacity for water and ice over a range of temperatures are available on the internet. For example **Engineering Toolbox** has [values for ice down to $-100^{\circ}C$](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ice-thermal-properties-d_576.html) and for [water up to $360^{\circ}C$](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-water-d_660.html). Page 16 of Monograph 21 from the former **National Bureau of Standards** (now NIST) has a table of values for [ice at temperatures from $1K$ up to $300K$](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/MONO/nbsmonograph21.pdf).

Comment: Yes by constant I was hoping someone would have done the integration up to room temperature or some reference point and then a simple linear approximation for the few degrees around that, but I guess if you want something you got to make it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> How then would I calculate the total internal energy of a liter of
> water given its temperature?

You wouldn't. The **absolute value** of the internal energy is rarely, if at all, of use. Instead, for thermodynamic processes the **change of internal energy** $\Delta U$ is what we're looking for.

Assume that for *some* substance, the internal energy is given by:

$$U(T)=U_0+c_pT$$

where $U_0$ is the internal energy at $0\text{ }\mathrm{K}$. For the simple case we assume $c_p$ invariant to temperature.

(If this is not the case we can apply instead:)
$$U(T)=U_0+\int_{0}^Tc_p(T)\text{d}T$$

Now if we move the system from $T_1$ to $T_2$, the change of internal energy is given by:

$$\Delta U(\Delta T)=U(T_2)-U(T_1)=U_0+c_pT_2-(U_0+c_pT_1)=c_p(T_2-T_1)=c_p\Delta T$$

So we don't need to know $U_0$ to calculate $\Delta U(\Delta T)$.

In the literature, in particular engineering thermodynamic literature, you will find data presented 'as' absolute values, like $U(273.15)$ data. These are not true absolutes. They are measured against some standard and are useful to calculate *changes of internal energy*, $\Delta U$.

The trick here is to assign a **reference point**.

Let's say that:

$$U(273.15)=U_0+U_1$$

And:
$$U(T)=U_0+U_2$$

Then moving the system from $273.15\text{ }\mathrm{K}$ to $T$ costs a change in internal energy:
$$\Delta U=U(T)-U(273.15)=U_2-U_1$$

We then **conventionally** state that:
$$U(273.15)=0$$
And $U(T)$:

$$U(T)=\Delta U$$

So that $U$ at $273.15\text{ }\mathrm{K}$ has become our reference point. All changes $\Delta U(\Delta T)$ can now be calculated from such tabulated values.

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of what is *normally* done. I wouldn't have needed to ask a stack exchange question to find the change in internal energy, or to know that it is normally taken with respect to 0 C.  

I have one of those "rarely, if at all" use cases and would really appreciate some way to calculate the *absolute* internal energy. I have searched and asking stack exchange is my last resort. And yes, as a matter of fact, for my purposes even the nuclear energy contained in the water is important, but I know how to calculate that.

Comment: Why, what is the application that requires absolute knowledge of internal energy in your case?